# Angular 2 Way Binding issue when using service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am attempting to just do a simple 2 way binding in my angular 7 app `{{value}}`. this works in almost all spots in my app as I expect it to, but in this spot it is not updating when the observable returns. I have obviously missed something in the current component I am working on. Please let me know if you see an error in the code sample below:

Type Script Component File

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ObjectModel } from 'app/models/objectmodel';
import { ObjectService } from 'app/services/object.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'object-form',
  templateUrl: './object-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./object-form.component.scss']
})
export class ObjectFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private objectService: ObjectService
  ) { }

  objects: Array<ObjectModel> = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getObjects();
  }

  getObjects(){
    this.objectService.getAllObjects().subscribe(data => {
      this.objects = data;
    }
  );
  }
}
```

Template File

```html
<pre>{{objects|json}}</pre>
```

I am sure I am just flat overlooking something insanely simple, but cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: are you able to get data back ?

Comment: If you console.log out `data`, within your `getObjects()` function, do you have data?

Comment: Have you dropped a `console.log(data)`in your `getObjects()` method to see if you are getting a value at all. If you get a value there, the issue is in your component or template, if you don’t get a value there the issue is likely in your service.

Comment: probably you are not getting data from your service and trying to convert to json is what the issue seems like

Comment: I am able to get data back when doing both a console.log(data) and a console.log(this.objects) within the subscription call back, but no data is displayed within the pre tags of the template. The entire template is what is above, but it is a child component of another component.

Comment: I have also attempted to use ngZone as I saw suggested on other sites (I have used this with signalr in other areas), but that did not work either. This confuses me even more, as if the problem were simply that the change detection weren't picking up the change then this would fix that issue.

Comment: If I add a button to the screen and simply call `console.log(this.objects)` it then updates the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You have common module imported in your appmodule or the module in which you are using this pipe?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not initialize your objects variable, just declare.
When you use inheritance I've seen strange cases when it initializes variables AFTER subscription fires.

```
objects: Array<ObjectModel> = [];
```

to

```
objects: Array<ObjectModel>;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I gave this a try and unfortunately this didn't get it. I am sure I have some little thing similar to this wrong somewhere. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1ktpd) which has your code and some of the suggestions below. The `ObjectService` returns an observable containing an array of objects and works fine with your component code.

I don't think you have enough in your question to allow a specific answer, here are some problem solving steps I would take:

- put an `*ngIf="objects"` on your `pre` element
- try assigning the observable returned from `getAllObjects()` to the `objects` variable in the component and unwrap it in the template using the async pipe: `{{ (objects | async) | json }}`
- check the structure in the Stackblitz against your code and update your answer with any differences between your code and the Stackblitz (I suggest you fork the Stackblitz I've created and add this to your question)

Looking at my Stackblitz might help, even if it is similar to your code, it might give you a new way of thinking about it.